# Replacing div content using jquery in a jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

So far I've been making an AJAX call to replace the content of a div with another page, using the following code:

```
<script>
    function fetchContainerContent(url, containerid) {
        var req = false

        if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            try {
                req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
            } catch (e) {
                try {
                    req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
                } catch (e) {}
            }
        } else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            req = new XMLHttpRequest()
        } else {
            return false
        }

        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            requestContainerContent(req, containerid)
        }
        req.open('GET', url, true)
        req.send(null)
    }

    function requestContainerContent(req, containerid) {
        if (req.readyState == 4 && (req.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1))
            document.getElementById(containerid).innerHTML = req.responseText
    }
</script>
```

I have tried transforming the above code to work with jQuery as below but it doesn't work. In other words, I am trying to mimic the end result of the above behaviour but it is nowhere near the same. In fact, nothing happens on screen, nothing changes. I should mention that I don't really need the Loading... but since the examples I've seen use it and since I'm not sure how to correctly syntax jQuery, I've left it in.

```
<script>
    function fetchContainerContent(url, containerid) {
        jQuery.ajaxSetup ({
            cache: false
        });
        var ajax_load = "loading...' />";

        jQuery("#load_basic").click(function() {
            jQuery("#"+containerid).html(ajax_load).load(url);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Thanks in advance. I'm really new to jQuery so I may have done something really stupid.

After all the comments received (thanks guys!) I have left only the following:

```
function fetchContainerContent(url, containerid){                   
var ajax_load = "loading...";               
$("#load_basic").click(function(){$("#"+containerid).html(ajax_load).load(url);});
```

}

but I'm still having problems as it does not update the page. No js error, nothing happens.

Comment: Please define "doesn't work". There are zillion of reasons we can think about. What happens? What happens not? Edit your question accordingly.

Comment: What part is not working? Do you see the "loading..." message and then nothing more or is something else? Also, have you tried firebug to see if any errors are reported?

Comment: You are right, I wasn't very clear. I am trying to mimic the end result of the above behaviour but it is nowhere near the same. In fact, nothing happens on screen, nothing changes. What was happening with the first snippet is that a div would get replaced with the code from the url, but now I don't get any response at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *only* fundamental differences I see are:

1. You're using a hacky-looking loading string `"loading...' />"`. This doesn't smell good.
2. You're hardcoding the containerid with `"#result"` instead of using `"#" + containerid`.
3. You're defining the `click` event in JS code rather than (apparently) inline in the element. How did it originally look like?

For the remnant the code looks fine.

Comment: 1. I'd prefer not using the loading... string but I've only seen examples using it so far, and I have not started experimenting yet.
2. Thanks for pointing this out.
3. Originally I was using an onclick with called fetchContainerContent. The idea is that on clicking on a link a predefined div gets updated with the new content. I'd still prefer to keep that logic if that is possible.

Thanks for your help

Comment: The `' />` part doesn't look good and it might malform the HTML. Sanitize it or get rid of it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
jQuery("#load_basic").click(function() {
    jQuery("#result").html(ajax_load).load(url);
    return false;
});
```

Note the `return false` statement at the end of the click handler. This will prevent from propagating the click event in case `load_basic` is a button or an anchor element.

Answer (score 0):

Is the issue that it isn't calling your callback method? You have to had the callback to the .load method.

```
<script>
    function fetchContainerContent(url, containerid) {
        jQuery.ajaxSetup ({
            cache: false
        });
        var ajax_load = "loading...' />";

        jQuery("#load_basic").click(function() {
            jQuery("#result").html(ajax_load).load(url, null, requestContainerContent);
            return false;
        });
    }

    function requestContainerContent(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
        // do replacement in here
    }

</script>
```

You'll have to adjust the code a bit in your requestContainerContent to do what you need it to do with the arguments provided.

Comment: No the problem is not in the way the methods are structured. Thanks for your reply, though!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I seem to have gotten it working, even if I'm not too sure about the quality of the code.

```
var ajax_load = "loading...";
$("#"+containerid).html(ajax_load).load(url);
```